# fixed position in Javascript

Tags: css-position

How can I set the body of my HTML into fixed position once I clicked a button?

I tried this code where in the "unscroll" is the id of my div container for my whole php file.

```
<button class="add" id="mybutton" onclick="myFunction()">View</button>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("unscroll").style.position = "fixed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your example should work fine,

Maybe one more thing you can do to see the result is update the position of your element, for example:

```
unscrollElement.style.top = "0";
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  const unscrollElement = document.getElementById("unscroll");   
  unscrollElement.style.position = "fixed";
  unscrollElement.style.top = "0";
}
```

```css
.add {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="add" id="mybutton" onclick="myFunction()">View</button>

<div id="unscroll">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/600">
</div>
```